# CSS procent width minus fixed width

Tags: width, padding, css

I have a padding that i want to minus on procent based design. The typing area have that padding, but makes the input longer than 100%.

can anybody explain what is wrong with my css:

```
input[type='text'] {
    padding:5px;
    width:calc(100% - 10px);
}

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="Username" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
input[type='text'] {
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XW2Zc/) and [this article about box-sizing](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)